# how to migrate to typescript from create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an app that I built from create-react-app. I want to now add typescript to it. so I followed this guide: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript

but I'm getting 2 issues. firstly, it's now requiring me to change loads in the whole project when I just wanted to migrate slowly and change 1 file at a time and have the app still compile. rather than do it in 1 big bang, is this not possible?

secondly I'm getting this error: `cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208`

but when I change this `"isolatedModules": true,`to false, and reload the app, it changes it back automatically to true and I have no idea why?

Comment: I think you will probably find it easier to start from scratch rather than changing one file at a time.

Comment: @MattBrowne that's not ideal as one of the projects im working on is massive, over a year and a half old from many developers and will need to be slowly integrated. is that not possible? :/

Comment: By "it's now requiring me to change loads in the whole project", specify exactly what it's wanting you to change. We can't help you otherwise, and you should be able to compile JS files just fine. As for the isolatedModules error, share the source of the file you're receiving that from. If it has no imports/exports, try adding a dummy `export {}` at the bottom so it's acknowledged as a valid module

Comment: @kingdaro what I mean is, I can see lots of errors in lots of files. I was expecting/hoping it would only give me issues if it was a `.tsx` file. also I have no idea when i change the tsconfig file and then reboot the server that it reverts the config back to the original one. as in, it doesn't let me keep any changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're specifying compiler options at the command line, but if so I suggest that you instead use a `tsconfig.json` file.

Typescript has an option `allowJs` that will probably be helpful (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Also make sure you haven't enabled the `noImplicitAny` option (it's disabled by default) if you don't want to have to write a `.d.ts` file for every `.js` file you import from TypeScript—this means that in the absence of a `.d.ts` (type definition) file, imported JS modules will have type `any`. (Ordinarily I would recommend *enabling* `noImplicitAny` but not until you're done migrating your code.) In practice, using `allowJs` and keeping a bunch of your code in `.js` files will be a lot easier than renaming all the files to `.ts` from the start. While it's true that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, when you start mixing code with type annotations with code without type annotations, you start getting type errors pretty quickly (importing JS modules as type `any` is an escape hatch).

Coincidentally, I just came across an alternative to TypeScript that claims to have a more sound type system and also easier interoperability with untyped JS code, but it's still in developer preview (and doesn't have much of a community around it yet). I've only read a bit about it and probably wouldn't recommend it over TypeScript, mainly for practical reasons (at least that's my initial impression), but it's certainly interesting...if you're curious you can check it out here:
https://www.onux.com/jspp/

Comment: I hope this answer is helpful...I realize it doesn't directly address the `isolatedModules` issue but hopefully it's generally useful.